# React build failed with error export 'experimental_sx' (reexported as 'experimental_sx')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

My React Project build pipeline failed with the following error:

```
$ yarn build:remote
yarn run
$ CI=false react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
export 'experimental_sx' (reexported as 'experimental_sx') was not found in '@mui/system' (possible exports: Box, Container, GlobalStyles, Stack, StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider, Unstable_Grid, alignContent, alignItems, alignSelf, alpha, backgroundColor, bgcolor, border, borderBottom, borderBottomColor, borderColor, borderLeft, borderLeftColor, borderRadius, borderRight, borderRightColor, borderTop, borderTopColor, borderTransform, borders, bottom, boxSizing, breakpoints, color, colorChannel, columnGap, compose, containerClasses, createBox, createBreakpoints, createContainer, createGrid, createSpacing, createStack, createStyled, createTheme, createUnarySpacing, createUnaryUnit, css, darken, decomposeColor, display, emphasize, flex, flexBasis, flexDirection, flexGrow, flexShrink, flexWrap, flexbox, fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, fontWeight, gap, getContainerUtilityClass, getContrastRatio, getGridUtilityClass, getLuminance, getPath, getStackUtilityClass, getStyleFromPropValue, getStyleValue, getThemeProps, getValue, grid, gridArea, gridAutoColumns, gridAutoFlow, gridAutoRows, gridClasses, gridColumn, gridRow, gridTemplateAreas, gridTemplateColumns, gridTemplateRows, handleBreakpoints, height, hexToRgb, hslToRgb, justifyContent, justifyItems, justifySelf, keyframes, left, letterSpacing, lighten, lineHeight, margin, marginKeys, maxHeight, maxWidth, mergeBreakpointsInOrder, minHeight, minWidth, order, padding, paddingKeys, palette, paletteTransform, position, positions, private_safeAlpha, private_safeColorChannel, private_safeDarken, private_safeEmphasize, private_safeLighten, recomposeColor, responsivePropType, rgbToHex, right, rowGap, shadows, shape, shouldForwardProp, sizeHeight, sizeWidth, sizing, sizingTransform, spacing, stackClasses, style, styled, systemDefaultTheme, textAlign, textTransform, top, typography, typographyVariant, unstable_createCssVarsProvider, unstable_createGetCssVar, unstable_createStyleFunctionSx, unstable_defaultSxConfig, unstable_extendSxProp, unstable_getThemeValue, unstable_resolveBreakpointValues, unstable_styleFunctionSx, useTheme, useThemeProps, useThemeWithoutDefault, width, zIndex)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 9):

This is likely due a transitive dependency with a wrongly defined version. I could fix the problem by updating *all* `@mui/*` packages to the newest version.

As of 2022-12-14 it's:

```
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "5.11.0",
    "@mui/styles": "5.11.0",
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, you can try to remove the `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and re-install the dependencies.

with yarn:

```bash
$ yarn install
```

with npm:

```bash
$ npm install
```

Comment: That works for me. Altough it is weird that older version worked till 14.12.2022.

Answer (score 5):

As the pre-posters already said: "MUI breaks due to incompatible internal versions".

I walked down the dependency trees and found, that, for whatever reasons, npm installs the wrong version of `@mui/system`.

While this is a rather strange workaround, you can fix the issue by manually adding and then removing `@mui/system`

```
npm install @mui/system@5.10.15
npm uninstall @mui/system@5.10.15
```

Checking with `npm list @mui/system` gives

- before

  [image]
- after

  [image]

Comment: It feels so wrong that this is the answer, but it was for me!? I had to lose the version tag in the uninstall, so just `npm uninstall @mui/system`

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.11.0 use older versions

The breaking change is regarding an experimental API:

> -import { styled, experimental_sx } from '@mui/material/styles';
> +import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';>

I used below versions and fixed this issue:

````
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.17",
"@mui/material": "5.11.0",```
````

Answer (score 2):

There is a new release: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.11.0

It says it has a breaking change in @mui/system.

Comment: what is the solution for this?

Comment: Use an older version of @mui/material; 5.10.17

Answer (score 0):

It is due to incompatible MUI versions:-
It worked when I migrated to:

```
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
"@mui/system": "^5.11.0",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.12",
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.6",
```